# Automorphism on $S_n$ sends given k-transposition to a transposition

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

For given integer $k>1$ and k-transposition $g \in S_n$, is there a isomorphism from symmetric group $S_n$ to itself such than sends $g$ to a transposition (a 2-cycle)?

It seems that for $k=2$ it is impossible:
[Is there an automorphism of symmetric group of degree 6 sending a transposition to product of two transpositions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493275/is-there-an-automorphism-of-symmetric-group-of-degree-6-sending-a-transposition)

What about the same problem replacing "transposition" by "m-cycle"?!

Comment: This possible only when $n=6$ and $k=3$. For $n \ne 6$ it is not possible because ${\rm Aut}(S_n) \cong S_n$. For $n=6$, the outer automorphism exchanges $3$-cycles with products of $2$ $3$-cycles.

Comment: @DerekHolt: That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Because all automorphism of $S_n$ ($n \neq 6$) are inner, so every automorphism of $S_n$ preserves cycle type of permutations. Is it true?

Comment: Yes that is correct - so you only need to consider the outer automorphism of $S_6$, which is unique modulo inner automorphisms.